# How-to: Add remove locations to the Windows [Vista/7] Search Index from the command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-search, desktop-search, search-indexing

Despite there being the popular GUI way of doing this from the Control Panel (Indexing Options) applet, which can also be reached through Windows Explorer > Options, I would like to add/remove locations to the Windows [Vista/7] Search Index from the command line

For Instance:

> C:\> **windowssearch.exe index add "D:\the\full\path\to\a\specific_folder"**

and/or

> C:\> **windowssearch.exe index remove "D:\the\full\path\to\a\specific_folder"**

Answer (score 1):

for add Folder to indexing list,you need install Windows SKD (6 or 7).
and indexing in win xp diffrent with indexing in vista / seven .
[the download Link SDK is (1 GB)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Answer (score 0):

You can also fine tune your indexing from the control panel:

[image]

(And allow me to suggest that you remove the reference to Bill G.  It is not appropriate here no matter what you personally think, and nor is it helpful to others I don't think.  "Two things are bad for the heart: running up stairs and running down people." -- anonymous)

Comment: @Elliptical references removed.  btw, good quote ;-)

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use `Indexing Options` applet in the Windows. You can tick the indexing of current folder in explorer

[image]

Comment: OK, so what is the command line? Since you're answering your own question, please change the title to reflect your answer.

Comment: @terdon I made your suggested edits and a few more for him