# Process Monitor capture filter (or scripting)

Tags: windows-7, event-log, capture, process-monitor

As you know, Microsoft distributes the Russinovich extremely powerful [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). It captures a lot of system events and has a filter to show only some of them. I want to record [a rare fault](https://superuser.com/questions/674506/can-windows-search-indexer-prevent-file-from-deleting) at specific file names. However, there is a lot of events in my system and the sysinternals log takes gigabytes of RAM recording everything. I am sure that I need to capture no more than file events pass my view filter. I do not want to capture other events. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the filter before capturing the data and make sure the option `Drop filtered Events` is set.

[image]

Also specify that the data are written to a file and not the RAM:

[image]

[image]